# jQuery: best plugin for table with fixed header

Tags: jquery, fixed-header-tables

What's the best jQuery plugin for creating a table with fixed header?
It should be crossbrowser compatible.
I'm needing this for creating a datagrid widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most people use [jGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) or [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/)

Answer (score 2):

There's also $.tableScroll() plugin

https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a table with fixed row labels as well, I whipped this up:

http://adamkochanowicz.com/blog/fixed-table-headers-and-sidebar/